# YouTube Live Streaming showing "Insufficient Live Permissions"

Tags: android, limit, live-streaming, youtube-data-api

I am doing an android application in YouTube Live Streaming. I was able to Live stream to my YouTube Channel using YouTube Data API V3 through my app. But the Live Streamed Events are limited to 7 to 8 per day. when I tried to give Live stream, if it reaches the limit of 7 to 8 events, I was Getting an error message like "**Insufficient Live Permissions**". But after one day I was able to give Live Streaming through that channel.

I searched the documentation provided by Google, but didn't got the information about limit in LiveStreams

please someone help me to get out of this situation.

these is my Google credentials object

```
 googleCredential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().
                                setJsonFactory(jsonFactory).setTransport(transport).
                                setClientSecrets(clientId, clientSecret)
                                .build();
                        googleCredential.setAccessToken(accessToken);
                        googleCredential.setRefreshToken(refreshtoken);
```

this is my YouTube Object

```
 YouTube youtube = new YouTube.Builder(transport, jsonFactory,
                    googleCredential).setApplicationName(APP_NAME)
                    .build();
```

Answer (score -1):

In [YouTube Live Streaming API  - Errors - liveBroadcasts](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/errors#livebroadcasts), the description of `insufficientLivePermissions` is

> The request is not authorised to retrieve the specified live broadcast. For more information, see [Implementing OAuth2 authentication](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/authentication).

Comment: ok, but I am  able to stream upto 7 or 8 live events. if it is not authorised then how Iam live streaming upto that limit ?. please tell me

Comment: Please, can you share OAuth code so that we can analyse your situation? :)

Comment: googleCredential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().
                                setJsonFactory(jsonFactory).setTransport(transport).
                                setClientSecrets(clientId, clientSecret)
                                .build();
                        googleCredential.setAccessToken(accessToken);
                        googleCredential.setRefreshToken(refreshtoken);

Comment: I couldn't find reason for your errors. But I was able to add live streaming video in a sample App using [YouTube Android Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/).

Comment: My problem was not playing Live video in Youtube player in mobile android YouTube Player ,  I Have to Live stream on YouTube Channel for number of times per day. Thank you.

Comment: I am experiencing the same thing. When I try on YouTube API try tool , it still gives the same error. When I try some another channel, it works.